# TypeError: Signature mismatch. Keys must be dtype <dtype: 'float32'>, got <dtype: 'string'>

Tags: python, object-detection, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, faster-rcnn

I am trying to use Tensorflow object detection API on Google Colab. Upon running model_main.py, I am getting this error.

```
/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/models/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:135 process_fn  *
        processed_tensors = decoder.decode(value)
    /content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/models/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:388 decode  *
        tensors = decoder.decode(serialized_example, items=keys)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/tfexample_decoder.py:524 decode
        outputs.append(handler.tensors_to_item(keys_to_tensors))
    /content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/models/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:129 tensors_to_item
        item = self._handler.tensors_to_item(keys_to_tensors)
    /content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/models/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:98 tensors_to_item
        return tf.maximum(self._name_to_id_table.lookup(unmapped_tensor),
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/lookup_ops.py:223 lookup
        (self._key_dtype, keys.dtype))

    TypeError: Signature mismatch. Keys must be dtype dtype: 'float32', got dtype: 'string'.
```

I have followed the exact procedure that is given in this [blog](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/training-an-object-detection-model-with-tensorflow-api-using-google-colab-4f9a688d5e8b). The following code is generating this error.

```
!python object_detection/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=object_detection/models/model/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config \
--model_dir=object_detection/models/model \
--num_train_steps=50000 \
--sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 \
--alsologtostderr
```

Is there anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: The error message is not helpful if you don't post the piece of code that caused it, could you post it?

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo Sure. I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I get Exactly the same issue. I think it comes from the decode of tfrecord file: /research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 388, in decode

Comment: I finally get the solution. You have to modidy /models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py and put in constructor  dct_method='INTEGER_FAST' ensure TF version 1.6 compatibility.